# JavaScript NodeJs - How to refactor this bit

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

So I am in a middle of creating a simple CRUD application, but I stumbled with getting MongoDB auto-incrementing value of latest created account.

To be more specific, I have written the tidbit below to enable the following:

1) When registering, do some validation checks

2) Check what was the latest account number, increment by 1

3) Create a new user, add to the DB

Now, if you see below, I've marked **three EXHIBITS**

1 & 2) For some odd reason, if I remove the code from the route itself, then it stops working properly, but I have no idea how to get rid of repeating code since the functions are pretty much identical, but removing either of those just breaks the sequence. How can I fix this and make my code neater?

3) How would I go about extracting this function into a separate one? After fiddling with this, I only get to the point where "accountNumber is not defined".

```
const getLastAccountNumber = function() {
  User.find({}, { accountNumber: 1, _id: 0 }) **// EXHIBIT 1**
    .sort({ accountNumber: -1 })
    .limit(1)
    .then(function(doc) {
      if (!doc) throw new Error("Error?");
      accountNumber = doc[0].accountNumber;
      return doc[0].accountNumber;
    });
};
// TODO: Refactor methods

router.post(
  "/register",
  [check("email").isEmail(), check("password").isLength({ min: 4 })],
  function(req, res) {
    User.find({}, { accountNumber: 1, _id: 0 }) **// EXHIBIT 2**
      .sort({ accountNumber: -1 })
      .limit(1)
      .then(getLastAccountNumber())
      .then(function() { **// EXHIBIT 3**
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
          return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const amount = 0;
        accountNumber++;
        const user = new User({
          email,
          password,
          accountNumber,
          amount
        });
        user.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send("Error registering new user");
          } else {
            res.status(200).send("User successfully added");
          }
        });
      });
  }
);
```

Really appreciate any feedback!

Comment: What is `accountNumber = doc[0].accountNumber;` supposed to do?

Comment: Also! `accountNumber++;`; accountNumber is never defined! Try adding `let accountNumber;` to the top of your code

Comment: @LeonardPauli that assignment takes the value of the latest existing accountNumber in the database, to let accountNumber++ do a plus one value (for example, my latest account registered has an account number of 4900, and the idea is that it registers the value from the database, increments the value by 1, and creates a new user with the new accountNumber that would be 4901


P.S. Adding "let accountNumber" didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relating to your error, I believe defining the variable by adding `let accountNumber;` to the top of the file might be enough to get your code working, (though I do not believe it to be a great solution...), though as you asked about refactoring:

- embracing promises: Imagine a water/data flowing through a series of pipes, and in each step, the data can be transformed. Keeping this linear flow often makes the code clean and easy to follow. If any error happens on the way, all pipes until "catch" are bypassed.
- if an error occurs and we get straight to "catch", we might want to handle the situation differently depending on the failure reason. Thus, we can add error wrappers like `ValidationError` to check for.
- furthermore, we can name the pipes properly, like `getNewAccountNumber`, which will work even when there are no accounts in the db
- arrow functions are nice

---

```
// error handling

class ValidationError {
  constructor (errors) {
    this.errors = errors
  }
}

const checkValidation = (req, res)=> {
  const errors = validationResult(req)
  return errors.isEmpty()
    ? Promise.resolve()
    : Promise.reject(ValidationError(errors.array()))
}

const successResponse = (req, res, data)=> ()=> res.status(200).send(data)
const errorResponse = (req, res, message = 'Internal Server Error')=> error=>
    error instanceof ValidationError ? res.status(422).json({ errors: error.errors })
  : (console.error(error), res.status(500).send(message))


// utils

const initialAccountNumber = 0
const getNewAccountNumber = ()=> User
  .find({}, { accountNumber: true, _id: false })
  .sort({ accountNumber: -1 })
  .limit(1)
  .then(xs=> !xs || !xs.length
    ? initialAccountNumber
    : xs[0].accountNumber + 1)


// route

router.post('/register', [
  check('email').isEmail(),
  check('password').isLength({ min: 4 })
], (req, res)=> checkValidation(req, res)
  .then(getNewAccountNumber)
  .then(newAccountNumber=> {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    return new User({
      email,
      password,
      accountNumber: newAccountNumber,
      amount: 0,
    })
  })
  .then(user=> user.save())
  .then(successResponse(req, res, 'User successfully added'))
  .catch(errorResponse(req, res, 'Error registering new user'))
)
```

Anyhow, I would prefer to do this as one transaction, if possible by using existing db-build-in solutions (eg. the _id is already "guaranteed" to be unique, the accountNumber using this solution not as much).

Comment: Further down the road, I would want to emulate sending transactions from account to account (say, send 40 virtual $$ from account 10001 to 10009), how would I translate it to a human-comprehensible id selection? As for your code suggestion, I find that incredibly neat, will try to create something similar

Comment: Glad you liked it :) Usually, id's are supposed to be kept "hidden". Also, do you want your users to be able to "guess" account ids, or see how many you got? I would possibly generate a "displayName" that is human readable (eg. 4 random nonsense words) and can be changed later (but not to anyone that has been used before). That way, it'll by easy for a human to identify between their most used accounts, while the id will be used under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const getLastAccountNumber = function() {
  return User.find({}, { accountNumber: 1, _id: 0 })
    .sort({ accountNumber: -1 })
    .limit(1)
    .then(function(doc) {
      if (!doc) throw new Error("Error?");
      return doc[0].accountNumber;
    });
};

router.post(
  "/register",
  [check("email").isEmail(), check("password").isLength({ min: 4 })],
  function(req, res) {
    getLastAccountNumber().then((accountNumber) => {
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
      }
      const { email, password } = req.body;
      const amount = 0;
      accountNumber++;
      const user = new User({
        email,
        password,
        accountNumber,
        amount
      });
      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send("Error registering new user");
        } else {
          res.status(200).send("User successfully added");
        }
      });
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: returns "TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;then&#39; of undefined".....wait a second, it worked!

Comment: @Altair312 Have you added the `return` statement to the `getLastAccountNumber` function ?

Comment: oh now I see what is different, I tried manually modify the code, but it didn't work; decided just to dirtily copy-paste and now works. So, when you do something similar, by placing a "return" next to a promise, then ".then" clauses work? Or how does it work

Comment: @Altair312 Now the `getLastAccountNumber` function returns a `Promise` that is why you can call `then` on the return value `getLastAccountNumber().then(....)`